# Why Spread syntax throwing error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object

I am using this code to create a document. Which works as expected.

```
await Promise.all(
  payload.exercises.map(async(exercise) => {
      exercise.user = user
      exercise.workoutName = payload.workoutName
      await Exercise.create(exercise)
  })
)
```

But to optimise  the code I want to use spread syntax with the `exercise` object

```
await Promise.all(
  payload.exercises.map(async(exercise) => {
      await Exercise.create({ ...exercise, user, workoutName: payload.workoutName })
  })
)
```

But when I compile it, It throws error `Unexpected token (58:36)`

Can someone please help why I am not able to use this on the back end while can simply use this at the front end `reactjs`

**.babelrc file**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "11.5.0"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon ./src/index.js",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
    "build": "babel src -d build -s --source-maps --copy-files",
    "seed": "babel-node ./seeders/index.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.2.1",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "2.3.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "6.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "4.1.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-preset-node6": "11.0.0",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "chance": "1.0.6",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-walmart": "1.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-filenames": "1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "lab-babel": "1.1.1",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be frank: I'm not quite sure what the problem is with your Babel configuration in Babel v6. It may be that there's some problem with the npm modules related to the transition from v6 to v7 though I thought all the naming changes handled that. I don't use Babel v6 anymore.

After replicating your problem, I've been able to solve it with Babel v7. Here's how:

1. I removed all the babel entries from `devDependencies` in `package.json` so it looks like this:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "async": "2.3.0",
     "chalk": "1.1.3",
     "chance": "1.0.6",
     "eslint": "3.19.0",
     "eslint-config-walmart": "1.2.2",
     "eslint-plugin-filenames": "1.1.0",
     "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
     "lab-babel": "1.1.1"
   }
   ```
2. Completely removed `node_modules`
3. Recreated `node_modules`:

   ```
   npm install
   ```
4. Installed Babel v7 *(sadly, the current docs that claim to be for v7.1.0 have an incorrect installation line for the CLI, I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/babel/website/issues/1928))*:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
   ```

   ...which gives me these `devDependencies`:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
     "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
     "async": "2.3.0",
     "chalk": "1.1.3",
     "chance": "1.0.6",
     "eslint": "3.19.0",
     "eslint-config-walmart": "1.2.2",
     "eslint-plugin-filenames": "1.1.0",
     "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
     "lab-babel": "1.1.1"
   }
   ```
5. Ensured `.babelrc` was set up to use the new `@babel/env`:

   ```
   {
     "presets": [
       ["@babel/env", {
           targets: {
               "node": "11.5.0"
           }
       }]
     ],
     "env": {
       "test": {
         "plugins": ["istanbul"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Then, `npm run build` worked as expected. The spread syntax was left alone (since Node v11.5.0 supports it natively).

Just to be sure, since an earlier version of your question used `"node": 4.3` (the `4.3` should be in quotes, btw), I switched to that, and it worked just fine, transpiling the spread syntax (and `async`/`await` and lots of other stuff, as Node.js v4.3 is really out of date).

Comment: It updates my `.babelrc` file `{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-decorators",
    "transform-react-constant-elements",
    "transform-react-inline-elements"
  ]
}
` Don't know why so And what it does. Could you direct me to some documentation which I can refer to know about the babel file

Comment: @Profer - I'm really glad to have been able to help. :-) The version of the answer you commented on didn't quite work, though (for me, anyway, once I tried to go back to your config after the `.babelrc` changes it made that you mention above). I've updated now to something that does work, though. Happy coding!